# CSS Polymorphism used in CSS3

Tags: css, polymorphism

I am reading book of CSS3 in that, came across with one word **"CSS Polymorphism"**. I have heard first time **"CSS Polymorphism"**. Searching on Google but not find much.

**My Questions:**

1. What is CSS Polymorphism?
2. How to use in css explain with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a generally accepted term, but it appears to be used a couple of times in the context of properties. Different CSS properties accept different values.

Polymorphism is defined ([by Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polymorphism)) as:

> The occurrence of something in different forms, in particular.

In the case of CSS, individual properties can affect their target in a multitude of ways:

```
background:#fff; /* The background is white */
background:url(img.png); /* The background is an image */
background:#fff url(img.png); /* The background is white with an image */
background:url(img.png) no-repeat; /* The background is a non-repeating image */
/* Etc... */
```

This is polymorphism.

[*Pro HTML5 and CSS Design Patterns*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vEgwjUiNB_AC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=css%20polymorphism&source=bl&ots=EZL20d67Be&sig=xq_vtpZi-BPp9_-t7cIHkDyfUjM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ijabUcubGoXIhAe5oYGIDQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=css%20polymorphism&f=false) describes CSS polymorphism (in relation to properties) as a *"combinatorial explosion of possibilities"*.

Comment: i am started reading Pro HTML5 and CSS Design Patterns & i find that "CSS Polymorphism" word.

Comment: Well the excerpt I linked to (from that book) does state that the author defines *CSS Polymorphism*; it's more used in the context of the book rather than an accepted standard piece of CSS terminology.